# merge file based on string in an array

Tags: php, arrays, xml

good day , 

so here is the idea , i have a bunch of XML links and i want to merge them into one XML and convert it into CSV file, but since put it one by one in a textbox put a lot of effort, i decide to input it in a single textarea each links divided by line breaks. so if there were 10 links so it should be 10 line of links in the textarea as well 

 **this is my code** :

```html
$str = $_POST['inp'];
$arr = explode("\n", $str);

$array = array(); 
$cnt=0;
$ct=0;

foreach ($arr as $line) {
$array[] = $line;
$cnt++;
};

function mergeFile ( DOMDocument $target, $fileName )    {
$source = new DOMDocument();
$source->load($fileName);
foreach ( $source->getElementsByTagName("resValidateFakturPm") as $row )   {
$import = $target->importNode($row, true);
$target->documentElement->appendChild($import);
}
}

$target = new DOMDocument();
$target->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><bunch></bunch>');

for ($ct=0;$ct<count($array);$ct++){
     mergeFile($target, $array[$ct]);
}


$target->save("res.xml");
```

but there is one tiny problem , when i put 10 of links on the textarea it didn't resulted 10 rows in the CSV files instead it only resulted 1 row ,the last one. with 9 rows before resulted blank.

where's my code fault ?

Answer (score 0):

You give $target to the function and modify a local copy.

1) Either change your method body to

`function mergeFile ( DOMDocument &$target, $fileName )`

or

2) `return $target` in function mergeFile and

```
for ($ct=0; $ct < count($array); $ct++)
{
     $target = mergeFile($target, $array[$ct]);
}
```